# Can't insert new lines on json

Tags: python, json, freshdesk

I am using the Fresdesk API to create tickets on my Django application. The integration is working perfectly, however, when I try to user the code `\n` to create new lines in the ticket, nothing appears on the support page at Freshdesk.

An example is shown below:

```
items_changed = 'Nome do Item: T-Shirt Masculina Long. Cubo Mágico \n Tamanho: P / Branco \n SKU: 1913511271 - Branco - P \n Tipo: Troca \n Motivo: Não gostei \n Preço: R$79.90 \n Quantidade: 1 \n \n Nome do Item: T-Shirt Feminina Gola Choker Cansei \n Tamanho: G / Branco \n SKU: 1916211244 - Branco - G \n Tipo: Troca \n Motivo: O tamanho não serviu \n Preço: R$79.90 \n Quantidade: 1'
 
payload = {"description": items_changed + ' Dados do cliente: ' + client_data,
                   "subject": "Troca/Devolução de itens",
                   "email": user_email,
                   "priority": priority['high'],
                   "status": status['open'],
                   "group_id": group['Atendimento'],
                   "type": "Troca",
                   "product_id": client[client_id]
                   }
headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
        }
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, auth=('****', 'X'))
```

The problem is that the output is not what was expected.

The final ticket is presented below:

> Nome do Item: T-Shirt Masculina Long. Cubo Mágico Tamanho: P / Branco
> SKU: 1913511271 - Branco - P Tipo: Troca Motivo: Não gostei Preço:
> R$79.90 Quantidade: 1 Nome do Item: T-Shirt Feminina Gola Choker
> Cansei Tamanho: G / Branco SKU: 1916211244 - Branco - G Tipo: Troca
> Motivo: O tamanho não serviu Preço: R$79.90 Quantidade: 1 Dados do
> cliente: Nome: Erico Scorpioni, CPF: 06734142990, Telefone:
> 456543456765, Endereço: Rua 1 / Fpolis - SC

How can I make new lines to appear in the final ticket?

Answer (score 0):

All control characters in valid JSON need to be escaped. So, you need to escape your newline characters with an extra `\`.

`items_changed = 'Nome do Item: T-Shirt Masculina Long. Cubo Mágico \\n Tamanho: P / Branco \\n SKU: 1913511271 - Branco - P \\n Tipo: Troca \\n Motivo: Não gostei \\n Preço: R$79.90 \\n Quantidade: 1 \\n \\n Nome do Item: T-Shirt Feminina Gola Choker Cansei \\n Tamanho: G / Branco \\n SKU: 1916211244 - Branco - G \\n Tipo: Troca \\n Motivo: O tamanho não serviu \\n Preço: R$79.90 \\n Quantidade: 1'`

Comment: when I try that the result is this:
Nome do Item: T-Shirt Masculina Long. Cubo Mágico\nTamanho: P / Branco\nSKU: 1913511271 - Branco - P\nTipo: Devolução\nMotivo: Não gostei\nPreço: R$79.90\nQuantidade: 1